# Perl MIME::Tools - CRLF changed to LF

Tags: perl, mime

I parse a multipart MIME with MIME::Parse. I wanna have the complete part, not only head or body. As far I see it changes CRLF to LF. Thats a problem.

```
use MIME::Parser;

my $parser = new MIME::Parser ();
$parser->decode_headers (0);
$parser->decode_bodies (0);
$parser->output_to_core (1);

open (F, "myfile.txt");
my $mime = $parser->parse (\*F);
close (F);

my $mp = $mime->parts (0);  // get the 1st part

my $ct = $mp->as_string (); 

my $h = unpack ("H*", $ct);
$h = join (' ', $h =~ /(..)/g); 
print "\n$h\n";            // inspect and compare with myfile.txt in a hex-editor
```

If I look into myfile.txt with a hex-editor line-separators are CRLFs (0x0d 0x0a).
If I check the print-output then they changed to LFs (0x0a).

Why is that? How can I get the original content?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Are you on a Windows system? If so, try `binmode F;` before reading from the file to disable the default `:crlf` layer that Perl uses on Windows. See [`PerlIO`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) and [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Comment: It's also better to use the three-argument [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), lexical filehandles, and especially error checking: `open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;`

Answer (score -1):

Your question is missing the important information of how the data look like which you decode. But I will assume that these either have the explicitly given content-type of `text/plain` or have this content-type implicitly (i.e. no content-type header given). `text/plain` means ASCII data (unless a `charset` header is defined) and line ends will be used specific to the environment where the data are extracted: this means CRLF on Windows and LF on Linux, MacOS and other UNIX or UNIX like systems. It does not matter what the original line endiing inside the mail was, all what matters is the line ending used in the target environment.

If you really want to have the original line ending then the content should be declared as binary (i.e. content-type `application/octet-stream` or similar, but definitely no `text/*`) and the data need to be encoded with an content-transfer-encoding suitable for binary data, i.e. base64.